# Include Errors Detected when folder for header files is located in the same directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Directory looks like this

```
cpr
   include
      cpr
other code stuff
   the code I'm working on
```

I've tried adding

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
${workspaceFolder}/cpr/include
${workspaceFolder}/cpr/**
${workspaceFolder}/cpr/
```

to includePath to no avail.

Code:

```cpp
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <cpr>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
}
```

Expected: code compiling with no issues.

Actual: `#include errors detected. Please update your includePath.`

Comment: Try `#include "cpr"`, `#include <filename>` is intended for system files (whatever that means, your compiler will know).

Comment: And obviously check that there is a file called `cpr` (and not, say, `cpr.h`) in one of those folders you mentioned

Comment: According to this https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr the correct filename is `cpr.h`. So your code should read `#include "cpr.h"`

Comment: Still get an error saying it can't open cpr.h

Comment: Well all I can suggest is that you take a good look at the documentation for Visual Studio Code (sorry but I'm not familiar with it). You're making some basic mistake, probably you're making a couple, so fixing one thing (like using the correct filename of `cpr.h`) doesn't fix things overall. It's easy to get discouraged in this situation, so read the documentation, make sure you understand what you are doing instead of guessing.